# JavaScript parse JSON and create Key Value array from that

Tags: javascript, json

i have simple json format like with this format:

```
{
    "Template": [
        {
            "ID": "856",
            "name": "users",
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "857",
            "name": "avatars",
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": "858",
            "name": "emails",
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

now i'm trying to parse it and create key value array such as:

```
var sArray = {856:users, 857:avatars, 858:emails};
```

my code is not correct for create this array after parse json and i get this error:

```
Message: TypeError: obj.Template.name is undefined
```

My code is this:

```
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    var count_templates = obj.Template.length;
    var template_array;

    /* Length is not static */
    for( i=0; i < count_templates; i++){
        id = obj.Template.ID;
        template_array[id] =  obj.Template.name;
    }
    for(var key in template_array)
    {
        console.log("key " + key + " has value " + template_array[key]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you make clear what output did you want ?
Either var sArray = {856:users, 857:avatars, 858:emails} ?
Or ["856:users", "857:avatars", "858:emails"] ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var data = {
    "Template": [
        {
            "ID": "856",
            "name": "users",
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "857",
            "name": "avatars",
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": "858",
            "name": "emails",
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ]
};

var output = [];

data.Template.forEach(function(item){
    output.push(item.ID + ":" + item.name); 
});
```

Although you may want to check if the object has the properties you're looking for first, but you get the idea.

**Edit** : Just noticed you wanted an output of type array. (even though you have {} surrounding your array. In this scenario, I would use `map`.

```
data.Template.map(function(item){
    output.push(item.ID + ":" + item.name); 
});
```

Thanks to @torazaburo  for keeping me honest and making me re-read the question.

Comment: i like your post with `data.Template.forEach()`. thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Note the support for this ES5 method : http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach

Comment: Why would you not use `map`? Anyway, this will output a string, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a simple [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) operation on the `Template` array.

```js
var obj = {
    "Template": [
        {
            "ID": "856",
            "name": "users",
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "857",
            "name": "avatars",
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": "858",
            "name": "emails",
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ]
};

var sArray = obj.Template.reduce(function(o, tpl) {
        o[tpl.ID] = tpl.name;
        return o;
    }, {});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(sArray);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6:

```
Object.assign({}, ...data.Template.map(elt => ({[elt.ID]: elt.name})));
```

This maps the elements of `data.Template` into little objects each with one key-value pair, where the key is the element ID (using ES6 [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)), and the value is the name. Then it feeds all these objects as parameters (using the `...` [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)) to [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which merges them together.

```
{ '856': 'users', '857': 'avatars', '858': 'emails' }
```

#### Using Underscore

On a completely different note, if you are amenable to using Underscore, then

```
_.object(_.pluck(obj.Template, 'ID'), _.pluck(obj.Template, 'name'))
```

Comment: it seems interesting can you please share url where i can read about ES6 lambda expressions

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
   for( i=0; i < count_templates; i++){
      id = obj.Template.ID;//Here you are not actually accessing the array index element
      template_array[id] =  obj.Template.name;//Here you are not actually accessing the array index element
   }

   for( i=0; i < count_templates; i++){
      id = obj.Template[i].ID;
      template_array[id] =  obj.Template[i].name;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = {
    "Template": [
        {
            "ID": "856",
            "name": "users",
            "Template_Id": 0
        },
        {
            "ID": "857",
            "name": "avatars",
            "Template_Id": 1
        },
        {
            "ID": "858",
            "name": "emails",
            "Template_Id": 2
        }
    ]
};


var temp = data.Template;
var res = {};
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    res[temp[i]['ID']]  =  temp[i]['name'];
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by using **reduce** function

```
var arr = {
   "Template": [
    {
        "ID": "856",
        "name": "users",
        "Template_Id": 0
    },
    {
        "ID": "857",
        "name": "avatars",
        "Template_Id": 1
    },
    {
        "ID": "858",
        "name": "emails",
        "Template_Id": 2
    }
]
};
 var data = arr["Template"].reduce(function (output , val){ 
   output[val.ID] = val.name;
   return output;
}, {});

 console.log(data)
```

Comment: This outputs `{857: "avatars", 858: "emails", ID: "856", name: "users", Template_Id: 0}` because you have omitted the *initialValue* argument

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. First of all as per sample output mentioned in your post `sArray` is not an array. It's an object.

Steps:

1. Fisrt convert the actual JSON text into JSON object
2. Get `Template` array from parsed JSON object
3. Iterate `Template` array and create a new JSON object as expected

Sample code:

```js
  var jsonText = '{"Template" : [{"ID":"1","name":"a"},{"ID":"2","name":"b"}]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var arr = obj["Template"];

var sArray = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = arr[i];
    sArray[a["ID"]] = a["name"];
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(sArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the variable type of template_array i.e

```
var template_array=[];
```

and then iterate by using obj.Template[i] not obj.Template. Here is working code:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
var count_templates = obj.Template.length;
var template_array=[];

/* Length is not static */
for( i=0; i < count_templates; i++){
    id = obj.Template[i].ID;
    template_array[id] =  obj.Template[i].name;
}
for(var key in template_array)
{
    console.log("key " + key + " has value " + template_array[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using map function

```
var arr = {};
data.Template.map(function(item,i){ 
   if(!!item.name && !!item.ID) //check if properties are valid
             arr[item.ID] = item.name;
});
```

return **`Object {856: "users", 857: "avatars", 858: "emails"}`**

http://jsfiddle.net/arunthakur14/hjgvkvLu/

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. The generic case is:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
    var o = {};
    o[obj[k].ID] = obj[k].name;
    return o;
});
```

You can modify this pattern to suit your need. Here, `k` is the current key being visited and `obj` is your data.

**Update: now returns json object**

Comment: This returns an array of strings, whereas he seems to want an object.